# Hudson Jenkins: 'Module Builds' list is not visible for some tasks

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have several jobs that builds multi-module pom. For some of them 'Module Builds' panel is visible. For some not. How do Hudson/Jenkins understand whether or not show 'Module Builds' panel.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The problem was cause of currently there was no maven task in build phase - there was task called  "Invoke top-level Maven targets"